# Datastores for multiple platforms. Should I be using CoreData for our environment?

Tags: iphone, ios, orm, cross-platform

We have native applications that run on Android, iOS, and Windows mobile.  For other devices (such as BlackBerry) a mobile web solution.  These applications currently do an initial large pull from our CMS and then parse XML from our CMS as its datastore.  This data is then available offline on the device.  We're looking for something more elegant than XML as we scale.

Here are options that we are weighing:

Option 1.  Export a sqlite DB to Android, iOS, and Windows 7 phone that they would all then use as its datastore.

Pros:  CMS exports the same data format to all devices

Cons:  iOS isn't using CoreData like everything I've been reading says I should be using.

Option 2.  Export sqlite DB to all platforms but have iOS insert data into CoreData.  We are toying with idea of having CMS export JSON format to iOS and have iOS insert into CoreData since our delta updates to the application will be in JSON.

Pros:  iOS is using CoreData and all of its benefits.

Cons:  iOS now strays from all our other platforms such that it needs an intermediate solution (converting data into CoreData storage.)

Curious if anyone has mobile applications on various platforms that require persistent stores and how your team tackled it.

3/22/2013 for minor clarification and grammatical changes.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon this solution while doing research:
https://github.com/AlexDenisov/iActiveRecord

It behaves similarly to CoreData, such that it utilizes object graphs.  It constructs the SQL statements behind the scenes for you so that you do not need to concern yourself with writing queries.

What I like about this solution is that iActiveRecord points to our exported SQLite DB from our CMS (which utilizes django) and we simply define our Obj-C class to match the schemas of the table (similar to defining data models in CoreData.)  After the class schemas are defined to reflect our table schemas, we can start using objects without worrying about sql queries.

CoreData could not do this since it required us to write a "converter" to get exported data from our CMS into CoreData's datastore.

Of course all the extra bells and whistles of CoreData are missing, but for our use cases, utilizing iActiveRecord out weighed other options.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is: can you really reuse any code on these platforms? Not much. Probably, too little to worry about it. In fact, if you don't have a common C/C++ library (in a broad sense, as in *a set of functions*) to process data in an SQLite database, there's not much code to reuse.

There may be cases where you heavily depend on certain SQL queries for good performance. Those queries may turn out to be very inefficient in Core Data. In this scenario I would go with SQLite and [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

If the queries are simple enough and you mainly need to display/edit the data, then going with Core Data will be easier.